# VBA macro export Problems

Tags: vba, qlikview

I have a problem with my code  it is showing the same data for each JPG I want it to show different data based on the "Neighbourhood" field but all I am getting is 100s of files showing the same  data on my export,
The files are exporting using all of the different variable names but all showing the same data

I have a feeling I am missing something but cannot find a resolution

code is below

```
 sub KnowYourNeighbourhood

 ActiveDocument.Sheets("SH02").Activate  
 Set t=ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet  
 set field1 = ActiveDocument.Fields("Neighbourhood").GetPossibleValues

 for i = 0 to field1.Count - 1
 strNeighName = field1.item(i).Text



 ActiveDocument.Fields("Neighbourhood").Select field1.Item(i).Text



 Filepath = "H:\My Pictures\"  
 t.ExportBitmapToFile Filepath & strNeighName &".jpg"
 next   
 ActiveDocument.ClearAll true
 end sub
```

Comment: Can you write before the next the following `Debug.Print Filepath & strNeighName & ".jpg"` and check the result in the immediate window?

Comment: tried this Unfortunately qlikview does not support the use of Debug

Comment: Then `MsgBox Filepath & strNeighName & ".jpg"`? The problem should be somewhere there.

Comment: Thank you Vityata ,This has fixed the problem however how can I get it to run through without it incrementally showing the msg box now ?

Comment: Honestly no idea... Try writing  `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))`, instead of the msgbox, it may work...

Comment: The MSGBOX is showing that it is running through the fields  fine however it is no longer saving to the drive location

Comment: Are you allowing System Access? There are a setting to the left in macro editor.

Comment: Hi yes the export issue has now been sorted it was not allowing system access thankyou

Comment: Great. I put my comment as answer. Mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you `Allowing System Access`? 
There is a setting to the left in macro editor.